# How to print a line multiple times and always with new line indentation?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a line multiple times but not able to get them indented in a new line, please support.

**code:**

```
Input_Name = input('please enter your Name')
Input_age = int(input('please enter your Age'))
Input_a_Number = int(input('please enter another number'))
Difference_Number = 100 - Input_age
print(( "Dear",Input_Name,"you will get 100 years old after" ,Difference_Number, "years", "\r\n")*Input_a_Number)
```

**Result:**

```
please enter your Names
please enter your Age2
please enter another number3
('Dear', 's', 'you will get 100 years old after', 98, 'years', '\r\n', 'Dear', 's', 'you will get 100 years old after', 98, 'years', '\r\n', 'Dear', 's', 'you will get 100 years old after', 98, 'years', '\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it.

```
Input_Name = input('please enter your Name')
Input_age = int(input('please enter your Age'))
Input_a_Number = int(input('please enter another number'))
Difference_Number = 100 - Input_age
print(("Dear " + str(Input_Name) + " you will get 100 years old after " +
   str(Difference_Number) + " years" + "\n")*Input_a_Number)
```

or has comma as you want

```
Input_Name = input('please enter your Name')
Input_age = int(input('please enter your Age'))
Input_a_Number = int(input('please enter another number'))
Difference_Number = 100 - Input_age
print(('("Dear", Input_Name, "you will get 100 years old after", 
Difference_Number, "years", )' + '\n')*Input_a_Number)
```